# Finding unmatched records in mysql having 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating website where the  1. students register themselves , 2. pay for the event & 3. then choose companies.
I have 3 tables named :

1. student
2. pay_confirm
3. company_name

Each Table is using `s_id` as foreign key.

- Data is inserted in student table when student register themselves.
- Data is inserted in pay_confirm when the student pays for the event.
- Data is inserted in company_name when student choose companies.

The student table structure consists of `s_id ,fname, lname, phone, email`. 
The pay_confirm structure consists of `s_id , status , timestamp`.
The company_name consists of `s_id , c1 , c2 , c3 ,c4`

I want to know the name & phone of the students who have paid for the event but not yet selected the companies.

```
SELECT fname, lname, phone
FROM student
WHERE s_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT s_id FROM student, pay_confirm
               MINUS
               SELECT DISTINCT s_id from company_name);
```

`student` table:

```
+----------------------------------------+
|  s_id   fname lname phone      email   |
+----------------------------------------+
| IWS101 sam molly XXXXXX sam@gmail.com  |
| IWS102 clay jen  XXXXXX clay@gmail.com |
| IWS103 rose glen XXXXXX rose@gmail.com |
+----------------------------------------+
```

`pay_confirm`:

```
+-----------------------+
| s_id  status pay-time |
+-----------------------+
| IWS101 1     XX-XX-XX |
| IWS102 1     XX-XX-XX |
+-----------------------+
```

`company_name`:

```
+------------------------+
| s_id    c1  c2  c3  c4 |
+------------------------+
| IWS101  A   B   C    D |
+------------------------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| fname lname  email           phone  |
+-------------------------------------+
| clay   jen   clay@gmail.com XXXXXXX |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I am using MySQL

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve])

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed. (`FROM student, pay_confirm` will create a cross product...)

Comment: thnks for the tip @jarlh. Could you also pls help me achieve my expected result.

Comment: Doesn't zealous' answer give you what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your description I think below solution work for you. here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/57c18/2)

```
SELECT 
    fname,
    lname,
    phone,
    email
FROM student s

JOIN pay_confirm pc
on s.s_id = pc.s_id

WHERE status = 1
and NOT EXISTS (select 
                  s_id 
                from company_name c
                where c.s_id = pc.s_id
               )
```

Output:

```
*------------------------------------------*
| fname lname      phone      email        |
*------------------------------------------*
| clay   jen    4534566677  clay@gmail.com |
*------------------------------------------*
```

Comment: what are you getting then?

Comment: @SAMUEL I have provided the working link of your example. please check it out. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/57c18/2

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your feedback and I humbly accepted it. I am also new to few things in SQL and keep learning. I have updated my query as per your feedback. Thank you.

Comment: @zealous . . . It looks much better!